# CSS/html display list in two columns if more than X amount of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamic list of elements.
I do not want this list to be too long. 
I could use:

```
ul {
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

But this always results in two columns. I would prefer to only have one column if there are only a few elements in the list.
So with 5 elements or less, I want this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But with 6 or more elements I want this:

```
1    4
2    5
3    6
```

I use css3, html, bootstrap 2.3.2 and jquery
Do anyone have some tips for the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply filter `ul` element(s):

```js
$('ul').filter(function(){
    return this.childNodes.length > 5
}).addClass('twoColumns');
```

```css
ul.twoColumns {
  list-style: none;
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ```return $(this).children("li").length``` worked for me

Answer (score 10):

If you are able to use CSS grid you can do this with [grid-template-rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows) and [grid-auto-flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) directive. Grid can be used in most browsers natively and in IE11 with [autoprefixer](https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-css-grid-and-the-new-autoprefixer/):

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, min-content);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  <li class="item">3</li>
  <li class="item">4</li>
  <li class="item">5</li>
  <li class="item">6</li>
  <li class="item">7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This splits items into columns of 5, which can result in three columns or more. Is there a way to limit the number of columns? For example, show one column for less than 6 items and two columns for 6 or more items (never three columns).

Answer (score 1):

### jQuery Method

This method uses jQuery to calculate how many elements there are and add a class based on if its 6 or more.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul').each(function() {
    if ($(this).children().length > 5) {
      $(this).addClass('column');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul.column {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

---

### CSS Data Attribute

If you can set a data attribute, this can be read within the CSS to calculate the outcome.

```css
ul[data-count="even"] {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul data-count="odd">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>

<ul data-count="even">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

***Pure CSS solution:***
CSS Grid doesn't allow us to spread the items out evenly, column does. In that case, you can count the items in your UL. If it has more than a certain number, you can add column. Like so:

```css
/* Splits list when more than 6 items */
ul:has( li:nth-child(7) ) {
    column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<h2>Example: 6 items</h2>
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
   <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
   
<h2>Example: 9 items</h2>
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
   <li>Item 6</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 8</li>
   <li>Item 9</li>
</ul>
```

In this case, it splits your list when you have more than 6 items in your UL. [Here a working example](https://codepen.io/NickNoordijk/pen/gOdrKZE).

Keep in mind that the :has selector isn't fully supported yet. https://caniuse.com/css-has

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CSS only solution: http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css

The article explains in depth how to accomplish what you want to build.

Edit: Example!
So the idea is to style lis different after the 6th list item inside a ul – otherwise put: when there are more than 5 elements we want to change layout. Possible CSS-only solution:

```
ul li {
  color: blue;
}

ul li:nth-child(n+6) { /* targeting all elements form the 6th on */
  color: red;
}
```

Of course this is assuming there are at max 12 items because otherwise the whole concept blows up or you end up with 6 items with blue color and n-elements with a red color.
Anyways, this will definitely work and is an answer (maybe not *the* answer) to OPs question.

Edit2: In the specific case of OPs example:

```
ul li {
  float: left; /* list items float left */
  width: 50%;
}

ul li:nth-child(n+4) {
  float: right; /* from the fourth list item on they float right */
}
```

Comment: Didn't check it in detail but how would you use it to apply style to parent? (seems really interresting, that's said). I guess, you could try to replicate UL column styling the LIs but that would change expected order of LI elements

Comment: Why styling the parent? Counting li's from the start and at 6 you can perform some kind of layout switch. Like, if there are more than 5 lis, then make the even ones clear floats or using flexbox or or or... dunno but I could think of several ways to solve the issue that way. =)

Comment: The order using two colums is from left to right then going down: `1    4
2    5
3    6` while styling the LIs, it would be: `1
2
3
4
5 6`  Now it depends if order matters or not, regarding OP expected behaviour. If you could provide a working sample with same order as using two columns, i would be very glad :)

Comment: I guess you can float left any LI < 4 and right the others but a concrete sample in your answer would be awesome