# Is there a way by which we can restrict number of rows in a multi-column ul display?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
$('ul').filter(function() {
  return this.childNodes.length > 5
}).addClass('twoColumns');
```

```css
ul.twoColumns {
  list-style: none;
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

This is same as the code that I have referred from another stack overflow question. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217009/css-html-display-list-in-two-columns-if-more-than-x-amount-of-elements) is the link.

But I have tried to restrict the number of rows and have done my research, but I wasn't able to find any solution.

Looking for primarily CSS solution, but JavaScript is also accepted.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the following is what you want:

```js
var numitems =  $("li").length; //get the amount of li elements, but you can be a little more specific depending on what your html structure is like  
$("ul").css("column-count",numitems/2); //then just divide that by two and give that as the column count to your ul
```

```css
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Note: I wouldn't necessarily go this route. I would take a look at [css-grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

More Info: The reason I wouldn't go this route is because `ul` doesn't have the greatest support to do this, while something like css grid can do stuff like this out of the box. There's a little bit of a learning curve, and I can see some scenarios where this would be preferable to it, but I decided to mention it because it's worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider CSS grid as follow to have a defined number of rows:

```css
ul {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:1fr 1fr; /*2 equal rows*/
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  padding:5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Code_Ninja what is not clear? it's only 2 line of code.

Comment: no i mean, does `grid-template-row` work in IE and Edge?

Comment: In most browsers, among which IE, Edge, FF, opera, ios safari and android browser are present which are widely used globally, this property is not working. Is there any way to achieve this in almost all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your JS code. You can do it jQuery way. Try `$(this).children()` instead of `this.childNodes`.

```js
$('ul').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().length > 5;
}).addClass('twoColumns');
```

```css
ul.twoColumns {
    list-style: none;
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>

<br><br>

<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```