# Split <ul> into two columns if <li> is greater than 5 using pure CSS

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to split a list into 2 columns if the number of child `<li>` exceeds 5, for example, in pure CSS?

In my example, I want the following to happen:

```
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
```

if the number of `<li>` elements exceeds 5, I want it to appear like this:

```
  <li>1</li>    <li>6</li>
  <li>2</li>    <li>7</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to break a list into columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509106/is-there-a-way-to-break-a-list-into-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are able to use CSS grid you can do this with [grid-template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template) and [grid-auto-flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) directive:

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, min-content);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  <li class="item">3</li>
  <li class="item">4</li>
  <li class="item">5</li>
  <li class="item">6</li>
  <li class="item">7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that the  template column declaration is unnecessary as the grid will create a new column automagically every 5 items. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zYGdEQq

Comment: Please add your answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. Break a list into columns versus start a new columns after X items are not the same thing.

Comment: @Paulie_D oh cool, I wasn't aware it worked like that with `min-content`. I'll update since that more accurately reflects that they likely want. Unless you want to post an answer?

Comment: Certainly there are other duplicates that are more appropriate then? This is a common question... [CSS/html display list in two columns if more than X amount of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33217009/215552) perhaps?

Comment: wow, this is amazing!  @Paulie_D, your codepen was extremely helpful as well.  thanks!

Comment: @HereticMonkey copied this answer over to the duplicate you mentioned.